# Разум и премудрость

Tags: семантика

Какое определение разума и премудрости, на ваш взгляд, является самым удачным?

Comment: Нам предлагается выбрать из списка или найти самим?

Comment: @М_Г  можно своё представление в двух словах

Comment: Чем плохи определения из словарей?

Answer (score 1):

Понятие "разум" связано с таким действием сознания как - различение. Понятие же "премудрость"  связано с житейскими, мирскими, бытовыми решениями (в отличие от понятия "мудрость", которое в ходу в духовных делах и создаётся разумом - различением). 
То есть: "разум" - одно из действий сознания; "премудрость" - действо на бытовом уровне, оцениваемое превосходным, так как решает некоторый вопрос.